# Calling a method to create an array in another class

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

**StudentDemo:**

```
public class studentDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int runit = 0;

        StudentMenu run = new StudentMenu();
        while (runit != 1) {
            run.menu();
        }
    }
}
```

**StudentMenu:**

```
public class StudentMenu {

    public Student func = new Student();
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    String input;
    String input2;
    String input3;

    public void menu(){
        System.out.println("Choose an option: ");
        System.out.println("1) Add a student ");
        System.out.println("2) Display student list ");
        System.out.println("3) Exit ");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {

            input = br.readLine();
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println("Choice: " + choice);

            if(choice == 1){
                System.out.println("First name: ");
                input = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Last name: ");
                input2 = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Number of classes to add for student: ");
                input3 = br.readLine();
                int numberOfClasses = Integer.parseInt(input3);

                studentList.add(new Student(input, input2, numberOfClasses));

                func.createClassList(numberOfClasses);
            }

            if(choice == 2){
            }

            if(choice == 3){
                System.exit(0);
            }       
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){ 
            System.out.println("An unexpected error occured.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Student:**

```
public class Student{   

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int classes;
    //Create array for classes
    private String[] classesList = new String[classes];

    public Student(){
        firstName = "no name";
        lastName = "no name";
        classes = 0;
    }

    //overloaded constructor
    public Student(String theFirstName, String theLastName, int theClasses){

        firstName = theFirstName;
        lastName = theLastName;
        classes = theClasses;
        System.out.println("Number of Classes: " + classes);
    }

    //Populating array
    public void createClassList(int classes){

        //Call array method
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{    
            for(int i = 0; i < classes; i++){
                System.out.println("Number of Classes: " + classes);
                System.out.println("Enter class " + i + ":");
                String input = br.readLine();
                classesList[i] = input;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) { 
            System.out.println("An unexpected error occured.");
        }
    }

    //Getters
    public String getFirstName(){ return firstName; }

    public String getLasName(){ return lastName; }

    public int getNumberOfClasses(){ return classes; }

    //Setters
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName){
        firstName = newFirstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String newLastName){
        firstName = newLastName;
    }

    public void setNumberOfClasses(int newNumberOfClasses){
        classes = newNumberOfClasses;
    }
}
```

Sorry if I pasted this in a little bit incorrectly.

I am trying to create a program the builds a list of students with their first name, last name, and list of classes. However, I keep running into this error after entering the first class:

```
ABRT problem creation: 'success'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Student.createClassList(Student.java:37)
at StudentMenu.menu(StudentMenu.java:37)
at studentDemo.main(studentDemo.java:10)
```

And here is the output before the error:

```
Choose an option: 
1) Add a student 
2) Display student list 
3) Exit 
1
Choice: 1
First name: 
t
Last name: 
s
Number of classes to add for student: 
3
Enter class 0:
eng
```

Right after typing eng, the error comes up.
There shouldn't be an OutOfBoundsException from what I can tell, as 3 is the limit of the index and I only typed in one class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you try to paste the code in correctly? It'll help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private String[] classesList = null;

//overloaded constructor
public Student(String theFirstName, String theLastName, int theClasses)
{
    firstName = theFirstName;
    lastName = theLastName;
    classes = theClasses;

    classesList = new String[classes]; // THIS

    System.out.println("Number of Classes: " + classes);
}
```

Try that instead?

Another problem with your code:

```
public Student func = new Student();
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

studentList.add(new Student(input, input2, numberOfClasses));
func.createClassList(numberOfClasses);
```

As you should notice, func was created with the **default constructor**.
The classes variable in your Student class will not be initialized with any proper value, and the String[] in your Student class will not be created properly!
You are invoking **createClassList** on func which is *created using the default constructor*, and not with the **numberOfClasses** value from the user's input.

> Read what I have said, WaterlessStraw! :)

What you might want to do instead:

```
public Student func = null;
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

func = new Student(input, input2, numberOfClasses);
studentList.add(func);
func.createClassList(numberOfClasses);
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
private int classes; // default value of 0

private String[] classesList = new String[classes];
```

Creates a String array of length 0, and that won't be of much use to you. Declare the classesList array as a field as you're doing, but assign to it a new array only **after** setting classes with a viable non-0 int value.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried creating the classesList after the constructors. I figured this would give the classes variable a value, wouldn't it? It still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @WaterlessStraw: Please tell more. "It still doesn't seem to be working" tells us little of use.